# Is renaming necessary for pure lambda expressions (let-free expressions)?

Tags: types, lambda, ml, inference, principal

Is renaming necessary for pure lambda expressions?
In ML, the input program expression has to have the property that every bound variable is distinct. I want to know if is it the same for pure lambda expression (let-free expressions)?

Comment: ML does not have that property: `(fn a => fn a => a + 1) "foo" 1`.

Comment: Can you explain more your example?

Comment: It's very hard to explain something when the question is broad and under-specified.

Comment: The question is about the algorithm of type inference. Core-ML is lambda calculus + "let". I want to know if we remove "let" from ML, do I need to rename bounded variables in the type inference algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

When you have binders, the only thing that matters is the relation between a variable occurrence and its binder. Using names is just a convenient way to express this relation (but you could use other techniques, such as pointers, explicit connections - as in interaction nets -, De Bruijn indexes and so on).

If you use names, there is a potential clash when the same name is used for two nested binders. In this case, you need some politic to discriminate among them, and the typical solution in all programing languages is that the variable is associated with the innermost binder with the same name whose scope covers the variable.

In practice, variable renaming is only relevant during (manual) reduction of a term, since you need to avoid the phenomenon of variable capture.
Consider for instance the term

```
                          (\x.\y.x y) y
```

where the outermost y is free. 
By beta-reduction this is (\y.x y)[y/x], and if we perform substitution naively, we get the term (\y.y y). This is wrong, since the argument variable y has been surreptitiously captured by the binder with the same name when entering in its scope.

In this case, we need to rename variables before performing the reduction, eg.

```
                          (\x.\z.x z) y
```

that, after reduction, gives us the new and correct result \z.y z.

Of course, in a typed setting, variables bound by different identifiers have different types, so it could be a good practice to rename them to avoid confusion.